# How to prevent jQuery duplicate function being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery `on('click')` function like this:

```
function enabled_click() {
  $('.btn_enabled').on('click', function() {
    alert('CLICKED');
  });
}
```

and then I have another post function like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_add_link', function(e) {
  var url = 'www.xxx.my-function';
  post_data(url, function(data) {
    if (data.status == 'success') {
      $('#my_wrapper').append(data.response);
      enabled_click();
    } else {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

The post function will append another `.btn_enabled` button. If i did not call the `enabled_click()` function on the success post, then the newly added `.btn_enabled` would not be able to trigger the onclick function.

But if I call the `enabled_click()` function like i did above, the already existing `.btn_enable` will then call the onclick function twice and alert `CLICKED` twice. Is there any way to make it so it only alerts once?

Comment: in enabled_click(), you should use off() to remove the click function you added before.

Comment: yes, the off() function is what i looking for, but i didnt know it actually existed. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event delegation by binding to a common parent, as answered by @qs1210, is a possible solution, and a very efficient one (because there's only one common handler instead of one per element). But depending on the code, it may require more changes.

As a compatible "drop-in replacment" just unbind the event handler before binding again. To achieve this in an easy and stable way, you can use jQuery's "namespace" feature for event names (see [`.on()`, "Event names and namespaces"](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)):

```js
function enabled_click(){       
    $( '.btn_enabled' )
        .off('click.some_namespace')
        .on('click.some_namespace'), function() {
            alert('CLICKED');
    });
}
```

Note: if you extract the event handler into its own function and use that as second parameter to `.off()`, you could omit the namespace:

```js
function click_handler(){
    alert('CLICKED');
}

function enabled_click(){       
    $( '.btn_enabled' )
        .off('click', click_handler)
        .on('click', click_handler);
}
```

*But* this only works it the `click_handler` variable is "stable": depending where and when the click handler is defined, the variable (`click_handler` in this example) could be re-assigned and `.off()` couldn't detach the previous handler anymore.

Follow-up: in your example, you only apply the event handler to newly appended elements (`$('#my_wrapper').append(data.response)`). You could alter `enabled_click` to explicitly take the new element(s) as an argument:

```js
function enabled_click($element){
    $element.find('.btn_enabled' ).on('click', function() {
        alert('CLICKED');
    });
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var $newElement = $(data.response);
$('#my_wrapper').append($newElement);
enabled_click($newElement);
```

Now the event handler gets attached to new elements only, and not to already existing which have the event handler already attached.

(I'm using `$` as prefix for all my variables holding jQuery collections, in order to distinguish them from pure DOM nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Your can write like this

```
document.on('click', '.btn_enabled', function() {
    alert('CLICKED');
})`
```

delegate event to `dom`, it makes everything harmony.